# What is dreamforce?

Tags: dreamforce

Can any one out here can explain me what is dreamforce and what is the use of dreamforce in salesforce. Why and how we are using dreamforce in salesforce and how the dreamforce and salesforce are connected. Please give some information regarding the dreamforce.

Comment: u will find answers for all ur questions here : https://salesforce.com/dreamforce/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dreamforce is salesforce annual event where salesforce customers, partners, developers participate to share knowledge, upcoming features.

Check this link [Salesforce dreamforce](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/)

Answer (score 4):

Dreamforce is the annual Salesforce convention.   It is not a piece of software within the Salesforce product line.  It provides opportunities to hear from knowledgable speakers about upcoming features, best practices, third party products, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamforce is one of the most important and popular technology shows. It hosts more than 100,000 attendees from all across the globe every year. Hosted by salesforce.com, named the world’s most innovative company by Forbes for four years in a row, it’s a golden opportunity to learn from Industry visionaries, product experts and world leaders who will highlight the areas where the industry is heading to!
To know more about Salesforce and its integration, visit: http://www.avankia.com/dreamforce2014